# Embed ASP.NET web pages inside PHP based web site

Tags: asp.net, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, embed

we have centralized back office system and we keep all products information,recently our clients asked us to deploy website to them, so they can show their products on their websites , the clients have their own websites which developed on php or java or whatever  ,  they don't like to use Iframe to show their products  because of some SEO problems in Iframe, We want to deploy our E-commerce website inside their website,We want to show our website inside HTML tag such as div,we don't like to design and develop new website for any individual client,  I am very interested to know your ideas , and any alternative solution.

Comment: Can you please reword this sentence: "We want to show our website inside HTML tag such as div,we don't like to design and develop website for any individual client". It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: It is not cost effective if we decide to design and develop new website for each client ,  we would like to develop  a centralized website which embed able inside their website regarding to each customer, SO They can show their product list and also product details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of focusing on developing a website that is embeddable, I would focus on one of two approaches: 1) Make web services/REST API, 2) Write a Javascript library.

**Making a REST API**

You can write web services (or a REST API) that a client could use to integrate into their site. This would expose your data/services/features to them.  They would have to do a little programming of course to integrate with the services, but it's an option.

**Writing a Javascript library**

You can write a Javascript library that will dynamically bring in data (calling web services of course that you host) and then you can take that data and place them into divs etc.

The advantage of this is that you can tell the client something like "just drop these 5 lines of code onto your page and it will do the rest."  It has a low barrier to entry for a client.

Comment: Sounds Perfect, but we concerns about the SEO,There has been problem  when we use Java script to build dynamic pages , or calling web api with JQuery , How can we resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm not an SEO expert. I would argue though that SEO is a very difficult target to hit. It is constantly changing (look at the Panda stuff from Google). I would try to hit as much SEO as I can of course, but you can't promise to do everything. Also if the client has good development skills they can make all the calls to your code server side and then do whatever they want to boost SEO.